# How can I store shell output into an array in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In my Jenkins pipeline, I'm trying to get this output into an array:

```
gitBranches  = sh (
script: 'git branch -a',
returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in `groovy` way:

```
gitBranchStr  = sh (
script: 'git branch -a',
returnStdout: true)
gitBranchList = gitBranchStr.substring(gitBranchStr.lastIndexOf("*") + 1).split("\n")*.trim()
```

Comment: I think it's better to first get rid of the leading `*` and then trim - or else you end up with a whitespace before the current branch. And for golfing you could use the spread operator instead of the collect.